# Modifying dplyr::lag function

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I am trying to use the `lag` function from the `dplyr` package. However when I give a lag > 0 I want the missing values to be replaced by the first value in `x`. How can we achieve this

```
library(dplyr)
x<-c(1,2,3,4)
z<-lag(x,2)
z
## [1] NA NA  1  2
```

Comment: Maybe `z[is.na(z)] <- x[1]`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg - yes it does:
`> stats::lag(1:10, 2)
 [1] NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8`

Comment: @DavidArenburg you are right... so isn't `stats::lag` calling *the* stats-lag?!

Comment: @Tim it seems like some bug in  `dplyr`s `lag`, [this](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/277) seems related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a modified function `mylag`:

```
mylag <- function(x, k = 1, ...)
  replace(lag(x, k, ...), seq(k), x[1])

x <- 1:4
mylag(x, k = 2)
# [1] 1 1 1 2
```

Comment: It gives me `[1] 1 1 3 4`.

Comment: @Pascal this is because Sven is also using `lag` from the `dplyr` package. welcome to Hadlywerse...

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using the `lag` function `dplyr`, there is an argument `default`. So you can specify that you want `x[1]` to be the `default`.

```
lag(x, 2, default=x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest adapting the function so that it works both ways: for lag and lead (positive AND negative lags).

```
shift = function(x, lag, fill=FALSE) {
  require(dplyr)
  switch(sign(lag)/2+1.5, 
         lead( x, n=abs(lag), default=switch(fill+1, NA, tail(x, 1))  ), 
         lag(  x, n=abs(lag), default=switch(fill+1, NA, head(x, 1))  )
  )
}
```

It has a "fill" argument that automatically fills with first of last value depending on the sign of the lag.

```
> shift(1:10, -1)
#### [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA
> shift(1:10, +1, fill=TRUE)
#### [1] 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```